# Dynamically build queryset

Tags: django

I have these classes:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Snippet(models.Model):
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)
```

and a list of searched keywords:

```
searchlist = ['Photo','Cat']
```

I would like to dynamically query the database for snippets that contain both (AND operation) of the keywords in `searchlist`.

From that list of snippets, return the list of unique keywords from each of the snippets, excluding the original search terms.

So far I have this:

```
# Turn list of values into list of Q objects
queries = [Q(keywords__keyword__exact=tag) for tag in searchlist]

# Take one Q object from the list
query = queries.pop()

# Or the Q object with the ones remaining in the list
for item in queries:
    query &= item

# Query the model
snippet_list = Snippet.objects.filter(query)
```

which returns the desired list of snippets but I'm unsure of how to retrieve the combined list of keywords, or if there is a more efficient way to achieve the end result.

EDIT:

I would like to achieve the following pseudo code on `snippet_list`:

```
for snippet in snippet_list:
    combined_keywords += snippet.keywords

ordered_keyword_list = getOrderedKeywords()        # <- I have this function already

final_list =  intersection(ordered_keyword_list, combined_keywords)
```

where `combined_keywords` is all the keywords in the `snippet_list`. And `final_list` is a ordered unique version of `combined_keywords`.

Comment: What do you mean by being unable to retrieve the combined list?  That code actually looks quite nice.

Comment: I've added an edit to explain it further, thanks.

Comment: Would `final_list = list(set(sorted_keyword_list) | set(combined_keywords))` do the trick?

Comment: Thanks, `final_list = list(set(sorted_keyword_list) & set(combined_keywords))` provided the desired union but the order from `sorted_keyword_list` is lost.

Comment: Since you've modified your question to an intersection instead of an union, would `final_list = [x for x in ordered_keyword_list if x in combined_keywords]` do what you want while preserving order with regards to `ordered_keyword_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution looks like this thanks to @Soravux and @Dave-Webb. I'm not sure if this is the most efficient method, but it works.

```
# Turn list of values into list of Q objects
queries = [Q(keywords__keyword__exact=tag) for tag in valueslist]

query = Q()
for item in queries:
    query &= item

# Query the model
snippet_list = Snippet.objects.filter(query)

combined_keywords = []
for snippet in snippet_list:
    combined_keywords += snippet.keywords.all()

ordered_keyword_list = Keyword.objects.all().annotate(count=Count('snippet')).order_by('-count')

final_list = [x for x in ordered_keyword_list if x in combined_keywords]
```